# Comparing gene expression overlap with hypergeometric distribution

Tags: r

I got stuck with an issue in analyzing my RNA-seq data. I have three tratments (Control, D1 and D2), and within each tratment I calculate DE genes between two groups (G1 and G2). Then I identify genes that become DE in both D1 and D2 compared to the control. Summarizing, I have (see also Fig. 1):

- 15,000 genes representing the entire transcriptome
- 1,000 genes representing those that become DE as effect of treatment, filtering those that are DE in the control. This group is made as union of D1 and D2 DE genes, respectively 450 and 600 genes.
- Intersecting the DE genes, I found that 50 of them are common to both D1 and D2, 400 are specific to D1 and 550 are specific to D2.

[image: Fig 1]

Now I want to understand if this overlap is due by chance or not. So I'd like to have a feedback on my solution and, if wrong, a possible answer to my problem.

I have my oberservation: out of 1,000 DE genes common to both D1 and D2, 50 overlap. Then, I draw 100 genes from both D1 and D2, and I counted how many overlap (bootstrapped 1,000 times). Let's say that the result of bootstrapped drawing is 10. Finally, I tested if the overlap observed and the one got by random drawing is different through a hypergeometric distribution.

I've done everything with R, using the `phyper` ([link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Hypergeometric.html)) as follows:

Here I have to use 4 values:

```
x = 10 (overlapping genes from drawing)
m = 50 (overlapping observed)
n = 950 (total DE genes - m)
k = 100 (number of genes drawn from D1 and D2)
lower.tail=FALSE
```

I got `0.007` which, if I understood correctly and my procedure is correct as well, means that the overlap I observe between D1 and D2 is not due by chance.

Any opinion about my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of intersecting filtered sets is problematic.  No matter where you set your criteria some genes will always fall just outside it.  This is especially true if you filter on P value and fold change (common in gene expression analysis). Instead, consider using `limma::contrasts.fit` to perform a test for genes whose changes are significantly different between D1 and D2.